# Split list values into comma separated strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I am picking distinct values from a datatable column like below.

```
var uniqueCC = dtNew.AsEnumerable().Select(s => new { cc = s.Field<string>("ID"), }).Distinct().ToList();
var uniqueCode = dtNew.AsEnumerable().Select(s => new { Code = s.Field<string>("EAI"), }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Now I need to get the values alone in a comma seperated string and I'm using the below code and it doesn't take the value alone.

```
string strCC = String.Join(",", uniqueCC);
string strEAI = String.Join(",", uniqueCode);
```

Please provide some suggestions.

List values

```
cc=1, cc=2, cc=3
```

Expected Result

```
1,2,3
```

Comment: What does the above code give you as a result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use LINQ `Select()` method to pass the *value alone* to `String.Join()` :

```
string strCC = String.Join(",", uniqueCC.Select(o => o.cc));
```

Or just return string values instead of anonymous type in the first place :

```
var uniqueCC = dtNew.AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<string>("ID")).Distinct();
string strCC = String.Join(",", uniqueCC);
```

Comment: Good one, I didn't even catch that those were anonymous types when I came up with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aggregate` functions available in c#.

Let say you have a list of string called `listOfString`, then you can call the aggregate function like this.

```
string outString = listOfString.Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b);
```

It will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to har07's excellent answer, if this is something you do a lot of the time, to save writing loads of code you could implement this as a static extension method, where you pass the datatype, the column name and your required separator - so it could handle different column datatypes and separators - in a separate file:

```
namespace Extensions
    {
        public static class LinqExtensions
        {
            public static String ReturnSeparatedString<T>(this DataTable datatable, string field, string separator)
            {
                var unique =
                    datatable.AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(s => new {cc = s.Field<string>(field),}).Distinct();

                return String.Join(separator, unique.Select(o => o.cc));
            }
    }
}
```

Then call it from your code by creating a reference to your new Extensions.LinqExtensions class, and calling it directly on the dataTable like this:

```
    var commaSeparatedIds = dataTable.ReturnSeparatedString<string>("ID",",");
    var commaSeparatedEAIs = dataTable.ReturnSeparatedString<string>("EAI",",");
    var commaSeparatedInts = dataTable.ReturnSeparatedString<int>("MYINTS",",");
    var dotSeparatedStrings = dataTable.ReturnSeparatedString<int>("OtherId", ".");
```